# Hundreds of sockets tied up with .Net remoting

Tags: c#, .net-remoting

I have a client-server setup which communicates via .NET remoting. We noticed after doing a netstat output on our server that the server had hundreds of socket connections to just one client. Once we shut down the client, the sockets, of course, disappeared.

I have built a small .NET remoting test server and client to see how extra sockets  could be created via remoting. So far, I have found that since remoting calls are synchronous, the only way I could bind multiple ports was to make several different remoting calls in a multithreaded environment.

Our production client is not multithreaded during its remoting calls so seemingly, it only makes one call to the server at a time. My question is, does anyone know of a way in which .NET remoting would leave sockets open like this with only one client? Any configuration settings that might lead to this scenario?

Comment: Maybe the client uses some stateful feature. Does Remoting have sessions? Or, maybe its using a callback channel. Or, using async calls that are not properly ended.